# Jersey 2.7 tracing on Glassfish 4.1.1 doesn't work

Tags: jersey, glassfish, trace

I tried following the instructions located here: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/monitoring_tracing.html#tracing
and it just doesn't work. I get nothing.

> Glassfish JVM Options: -Djersey.config.server.tracing.type=ON_DEMAND
>   Advance REST Client Headers:  X-Jersey-Tracing-Accept: whatever
>   X-Jersey-Tracing-Threshold: VERBOSE Content-Type:
>   application/x-jersey-test OR Content-Type: application/json

NOTE: Equivalent curl call doesn't either

So, how do I get Jersey tracing working?